# NodeJS: Should I Use a Promise to Peform Preprocessing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, promise

NodeJS + Express. I am trying to achieve the following:

- client sends in post request with the following JSON document `data={text: "I love Stackoverflow", shouldPreprocess: <true or false>}`;
- I need to call an external WebSocket service to do sentiment analysis on the text and return the result as JSON, e.g. {sentiment: 'positive'};
- However, if shouldPreprocess is true, I should call another preprocessing service before;

Questions:

1. I'm not sure what the right way to do this is, but here are two attempts. I feel like they are both hacky.
2. I'm not sure how to handle invalid input from the client. Details below.

```
router.post('/analyse', function (req, res, next) {
    const data = req.body;

    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined' || typeof data.shouldPreprocess === 'undefined') {
        return next(new Error('Please provide text and flag'));
    }

    analyseSentiment(data.text, data.shouldPreprocess)
        .then(doc => res.json(doc))
        .catch(err => next(err));
});

function analyseSentiment(text, shouldPreprocess) {
    let promise;
    if (shouldPreprocess === true) {
        textP = preprocess(text);
    } else promise = new Promise((res, req) => res(text));
    return textP
        .then(text => axios.post(<URL to sentiment analyser>, text))

function preprocess(text) {
    const ws = WebSocket(<URL of preprocessor>);
    // But what if I wanted to check for some property of text here and throw an error
    // that gets sent to the client, just as I do in the main function, i.e. in router.post above?
    ws.on('open', () => ws.send(text));
    return new Promise((res, rej) => ws.on('message', preprocText => res(preprocText)));
}
```

So that's the first way. It feels hacky because I create a useless promise in analyseSentiment that just returns the text, so that I have a unified way of dealing with both preprocessing and non-preprocessing scenarios. Please also see the question in the comment in function `preprocess` above.

The second way is to do everything in `router.post`, i.e. something like:

```
router.post('/analyse', function (req, res, next) {
    const data = req.body;

    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined' || typeof data.shouldPreprocess === 'undefined') {
        return next(new Error('Please provide text and flag'));
    }

    if (data.shouldPreprocess) {
        preprocess(data.text)
            .then(text => axios.post(<URL to sentiment analyser>, text)))
            .then(doc => res.json(doc))
            .catch(err => next(err));
    } else {
        axios.post(<URL to sentiment analyser>, text)
            .then(doc => res.json(doc))
            .catch(err => next(err));
    }

});
```

But off course there is the duplicated code fragment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to decouple preprocessing and validation into [express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) and put them in front of the main handler, this may look something like as follows:

```
const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const data = req.body;

  if (typeof data.text === 'undefined' || typeof data.shouldPreprocess === 'undefined') {
    return next(new Error('Please provide text and flag'));
  }
  return next();
}

const preprocess = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.shouldPreprocess) {
    const ws = WebSocket('<URL of preprocessor>');
    ws.on('message', preprocText => {
      req.body.text = preprocText;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

router.post('/analyse', validate, preprocess, function (req, res, next) {
  const text = req.body.text;

  axios.post('<URL to sentiment analyser>', text)
    .then(doc => res.json(doc))
    .catch(err => next(err));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would leverage the fact that in Express you can pass multiple functions as request handlers. They will be called one after another when you call `next()` without argument.

Example implementation:

```
router.post('/analyse', validate, preprocess, analyse)

function validate (req, res, next) {
  let text = req.body.text
  let preprocess = req.body.shouldPreprocess
  if (typeof text === 'string' &&
      text.length > 0 &&
      text.length < 400 &&
      typeof preprocess === 'boolean') {
    next() // validation complete, go to the next request handler
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ reason: 'Please provide text and flag' })
  }
}

function preprocess (req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.shouldPreprocess) {
    const ws = WebSocket(<URL of preprocessor>)

    ws.on('open', () => ws.send(text))
    ws.on('message', preprocessed_text => {
      // check for some properties of text
      // this function is not implemented here
      if (validatePreprocessedText(preprocessed_text) {
        // send error to client
        return res.status(400).json({ reason: 'Malformed preprocessing result.' })
      }
      // seems legit, go on...
      res.locals.text_to_analyze = preprocessed_text
      next()
    }
    ws.on('error', next) // or return res.status(500).json({ reason: 'whatever...' })
  } else {
    res.locals.text_to_analyze = req.body.text
    next() // nothing to see here, move on...
  }
}

function analyse (req, res, next) {
  axios.post(<URL to sentiment analyser>, res.locals.text_to_analyze)
    .then(reply => res.json(reply.data))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).json({ reason: 'Sentiment service has blown up.' })
    })
}
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense thank you very much. The reason I accepted the other response is that it was posted first - and the idea is the same.